# Pythonic sort a list of dictionaries in a tricky order

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of id's sorted in a proper oder:

```
ids = [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 0, 3]
```

I also have a list of dictionaries, sorted in some random way:

```
rez = [{'val': 7, 'id': 1}, {'val': 8, 'id': 2}, {'val': 2, 'id': 3}, {'val': 0, 'id': 4}, {'val': -1, 'id': 5}, {'val': -4, 'id': 6}, {'val': 9, 'id': 0}]
```

My intention is to sort `rez` list in a way that corresponds to `ids`:

```
rez = [{'val': 7, 'id': 1}, {'val': 8, 'id': 2}, {'val': 0, 'id': 4}, {'val': -4, 'id': 6}, {'val': -1, 'id': 5}, {'val': 9, 'id': 0}, {'val': 2, 'id': 3}]
```

I tried:

```
rez.sort(key = lambda x: ids.index(x['id']))
```

However that way is too slow for me, as len(ids) > 150K, and each dict actually had a lot of keys (some values there are strings). Any suggestion how to do it in the most pythonic, but still fastest way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to `sort` because `ids` specifies the entire ordering of the result. You just need to pick the correct elements by their ids:

```
rez_dict = {d['id']:d for d in rez}
rez_ordered = [rez_dict[id] for id in ids]
```

Which gives:

```
>>> rez_ordered
[{'id': 1, 'val': 7}, {'id': 2, 'val': 8}, {'id': 4, 'val': 0}, {'id': 6, 'val': -4}, {'id': 5, 'val': -1}, {'id': 0, 'val': 9}, {'id': 3, 'val': 2}]
```

This should be faster than sorting because it can be done in linear time on average, while sort is O(nlogn).

Note that this assumes that there will be one entry per id, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. If you need to speed it up, because your list is too long and you are having quadratic complexity, you can turn the list into a dictionary first, mapping the ids to their respective indices.

```
indices = {id_: pos for pos, id_ in enumerate(ids)}
rez.sort(key = lambda x: indices[x['id']])
```

This way, `indices` is `{0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 6, 4: 2, 5: 4, 6: 3}`, and `rez` is

```
[{'id': 1, 'val': 7}, 
 {'id': 2, 'val': 8}, 
 {'id': 4, 'val': 0}, 
 {'id': 6, 'val': -4}, 
 {'id': 5, 'val': -1}, 
 {'id': 0, 'val': 9}, 
 {'id': 3, 'val': 2}]
```